# Suppose $g\geq0$ and $E[g(X)] = 0$. Then $P(g(X)>0) = 0$. Hence $g(X) = 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$\textbf{Motivation: }$ I was thinking about what happens when $\text{Var}(X)= 0$. It is known that this happens if and only if $X=a$ for some constant $a$. The proof in one direction (assuming $X=a$) is trivial. To do the other I found some argument, which basically boils down to the proposition below. Problem is that I don't know if the proposition is correct, and I don't know whether my proof for it is correct.

So the question is whether the following is sound:

$\textbf{Proposition: }$Suppose $g\geq0$ and $E[g(X)] = 0$. Then $P(g(X)>0) = 0$. Hence $g(X) = 0$ a.s.

$\textbf{Proof: }$ Suppose $g\geq0$ and $E[g(X)] = 0$ but now suppose $P(g(X)>0)\neq 0$. Hence $g(X)$ is non-zero somewhere with non-zero probability. Suppose it is non-zero on some $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$0=E[g(X)] = \int_\mathbb{R}g(X)dF(x) = \int_Ag(X)dF(x).$$
Since $g>0$ on $A$ this is a contradiction.

$\textbf{Application: }$ Now take $g(X) = (X-E(X))^2$. Then $E[g(X)] = 0$ implies $X = E(X)$ almost everywhere since $P(X-E(X) = 0) = 1$.

Comment: Do note: I have not done measure theory yet (beside when talking about Lebesgue integration), and I strongly suspect this has something more to do with measure theory.

Comment: Looks right to me. I don't know any measure theory either, but I don't think you need that much machinery.

Comment: It feels like Markov's inequality could be relevant here: if $Z$ is a nonnegative RV, then for some $a >0$, $Pr(Z\geq a) \leq E[Z]/a$. So what if you take $Z = g(X) + \sqrt{a}$, and look at the limit as $a\to 0$? (Also your proof looks right, but I'm also terrified of measure theory, so thinking of an alternative...)

Comment: The Proposition is correct but the formulation is unnecessarily cumbersome in my opinion. This formulation might be a little bit better: „Let $Y$ be a random variable that is non-negative almost everywhere and $\mathsf E(Y)=0$. Then $Y=0$ almost everywhere.“

Comment: If $g$ is non-zero on some $A\subseteq \mathbb R$, it cannot contradicts to $\mathbb Eg(X)=0$. Say, $g(x)=x^2\mathbb 1_{x\leq 0}$ is positive on whole halfline and for $X=3$ a.s. $\mathbb E[g(X)]=0$. None contradiction arises.

Comment: @NCh, I don't understand your counterexample, how is $E[g(X)] = 0$?

Comment: Since $X=3>0$, $g(X)=g(3)=0$.

Comment: @NCh yes, but I really don't see why that is a counterexample? In fact, I'm quite sure it $\textbf{isn't}$ a counterexample, since you didn't say how $X$ is distributed, which we need to know in order to know $E[g(X)]$.

Comment: All is said above on the distribution of $X$: $X=3 $ a.s. means that $X$ take a unique constant value $3$ with probability $1$.

Comment: @NCh Ah, I see now. It still isn't a counterexample though. If $X=3$ a.s, then $g(X) = 0$ a.s, since you defined $g$ to be zero on the positive half-line, so your $g$ is not a good counterexample.

I'm pretty sure the proposition and proof are correct at this point.

Comment: @NCh This confusion is because of OP's choice of notation: Indeed the correct conclusion is $g(X)=0$ a.s. and not $g=0$ a.s. (the latter doesn't really make sense actually and could be avoided completely by using my suggested formulation from above)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Not only. What is $A\subseteq \mathbb R$? It is a set in domain of $g$, not in domain of $X$. So it is hardy interpreted as a set of $\omega$ s.t. $g(X(\omega))>0$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, I see. Indeed I was confused, and $g=0$ does not make sense, while $g(X)$ as a r.v being zero a.s does make sense. This is good because it means that I didn't really understand the material I am studying at the moment. So, is NCh's counterexample valid and my proof incorrect? In my proof I suppose I meant $A\subseteq \text{im}X$. That is, there is some region of $\mathbb{R}$ where $X$ takes values s.t $g(X)>0$ here. This corresponds to saying there is a region $B\subseteq \Omega$ s.t $g(X)(\omega)$ is non-zero here, but I wanted to stay in the reals for the integral.